# Access Spring MVC Model data in imported js file

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on a project with Spring MVC with java as the backend and HTML(JSP)/CSS/JS as the frontend.
In my controller in java I am adding data to the model like this

```
model.addAttribute("someData", theData);
```

which I can easily access in the JSP file like this

```
${theData} or "${theData}"
```

The problem for me is that this only works in my JSP file. I am importing other css and js files there like

```
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/javascript/main.js'/>"></script>
```

and they seem to have no access to the model. I understand that there is no model at runtime on the clientside, but the javascript files are served by the server the same way as the HTML/JSP file, so why does this not work? Or is there any kind of setting I have to use?

I realize that inline js code in my JSP file works, but this is not very flexible and just not a "real" solution for me. Also I would like to avoid additional calls to the server (like AJAX) to get my data.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> ...but the javascript files are served by the server the same way as the HTML/JSP file...

No, this is not true.  The static JavaScript, CSS, and HTML files are being served by the web server as-is, with no processing.  The EL snippet in your example...

```
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/javascript/main.js'/>"></script>
```

...is only generating a concrete URL based upon the relative URL that you have provided as an argument to the function.  There is no knowledge embedded of what `main.js` is or does. Your JSP files are explicitly processed by the Java servlet container.  This is why it has knowledge about your application, beans, models, and all.  This is a gross oversimplification, but hopefully it gets the point across.

**Edit**

You can use JSON from static files in your JSP, but you have to read, process, and store them as Java objects in a bean in your application. I am not sure why you would want to do this, though, since it is so easy to read JSON data via JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there might be a way to process the js files like ths JSP files. So the only way is to use inline scripts then. Not a very elegant solution :( But thanks for the explanation.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with your JavaScript files? Are you trying to generate them dynamically at runtime?

Comment: Yes, kindoff. I have data in my model that changes from time to time and whenever a user opens the webpage it draws some diagrams which should always contain the (at this point in time) current data. The diagrams are made with js, so I need that data there. Cleanest way would be to simply write something like var data = "${theData}" and let spring insert the data. It doesn't have to change until reload anyways.

Comment: I think the better thing to do here would be to create a controller method that just returns JSON data that is generated at runtime and then have a JavaScript function consume this.  This would allow for safer handling of the data.

Comment: @CodeO - There _is_ a way to process js, css, and indeed any file like the jsp file, but that process does much more than substitute variables and the result of running js or css through it makes those types of files unusable. It would not be terribly difficult (in my opinion) to write your own processor that does only the variable substitution.

Answer (score 1):

willOEM gave you a good background. So static files don't know about the model values, but also there's no need for this as you can always code your way out.

If you're calling any function from your `main.js` within your jsp, than at that point you should use the `${theData}` as a function argument. If not, you can always use a data attribute on a dom element, store your model variable there, and access it inside your js file, so something like

```
<div data-the-data="${theData}">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: I've found using `data-*` data attributes like this incredibly useful, much better than _making s--- up_ and just stashing the data somewhere hidden in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have "solved" it now by defining the databinding inline in the html document

```
var theData = "{theData}";
```

and then using that in my standard javascript file.
Not really perfect but seems to be the best working solution.